# Channel not receiving local broadcasts in test environment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently writing a small game with Elixir and Phoenix and I'm running into an issue in writing tests to monitor my game's performance.

Basically I've got a GenServer that loops infinitely by sending itself casts that acts as the game's main loop, handling most of the logic. Let's call this the "gameloop". On every iteration, the gameloop sends a message (through `MyAppWeb.Endpoint.broadcast` to a channel containing the updated game state. The channel receives this message through `handle_in` and forwards the new game state to all connected clients. The channel also sends a message containing the time at which the state update was received to another GenServer which keeps track of various metrics.

This works great in dev and production, but not in tests. When in the test environment, the channel doesn't seem to receive the broadcasts from the gameloop. I can connect to the socket, join the channel and push messages to it from the test case (thanks to `ChannelCase`), but what I'm doing is more akin to an integration test, so sending messages to the channel from the test case is pointless.

Is this behaviour normal? If so, is there a way for me to change my game or my test's architecture that would work better? If not, what step am I missing? I've looked around on the web but couldn't find anything about this. I've also tried to play around with the test environment configuration (notably enabling the `server` option in the Endpoint configuration), but couldn't get it to work.

Here's a little bit of code to better illustrate what I'm doing.

The Gameloop GenServer:

```
defmodule MyApp.Gameloop do
  use GenServer
  alias MyAppWeb.Endpoint

  # Client

  def start_link([]) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  # Server (callbacks)

  @impl true
  def init([]), do: {:ok, %{}}

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:loop, state) do
    updated_state = handle_game_logic(state)

    Endpoint.broadcast!("game_state", "new_state", updated_state)

    Process.send_after(self(), :loop, calculate_time_to_wait_based_on_tick_rate())

    {:noreply, updated_state}
  end
end
```

The socket:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.SpectateSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "game_state", MyAppWeb.GameStateChannel

  def connect(_params, socket), do: {:ok, socket}

  def id(_socket), do: nil
end
```

The channel:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.GameStateChannel do
  alias MyApp.Monitor
  alias :erlang, as: Erlang

  use MyAppWeb, :channel

  def join("game_state", _payload, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("new_state", payload, socket) do
    broadcast(socket, "new_state", payload)
    Monitor.store_broadcast_time(Erlang.monotonic_time())
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

Again, this works fine in dev/prod, but the channel's `handle_in` is never called in tests.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: “I don't have time right now”—come here to ask when you have a sufficient amount of time to state the question, please. Just dropping a wall of letters without any code in a hope that people out there have _more time than you_ is not an expected behaviour here on SO. Thanks.

Comment: I've added some sample code now. Sorry for the inconvenience.